# How to setup the firebase admin SDK Service Worker credentials for custom token minting via third party JWT libraries for firebase function emulators?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-admin-sdk, firebase-tools

I am working with the Firebase admin SDK on Firebase Cloud Functions. I am trying to set up the admin SDK so that I can mint my own tokens using third-party JWT libraries. The Firebase docs have somewhat unclear documentation on this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#using_a_service_account_json_file). It seems that there have been many changes to this process and there are some nuances in my application that makes getting a clear answer difficult using existing documentation.

In my case, I am running the admin SDK in a google managed environment (firebase cloud functions), based on the docs, simply using `initializeApp()` with no arguments should work in production/nonlocal environments.

That being said, for local testing using emulated functions, I am having trouble determining the correct way to set up the local environment to test functions and token creation *without* pushing to various online staging environments.

For example, the documentation above contradicts the seemingly similar documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) The shell commands are different but there may be some nuance that I am missing. One solution is to ship the service worker JSON with my code when deploying (assuming I keep it out of public version control) and specify it in the code on admin SDK init. I do not like this option as I feel there is a simpler alternative since I am running in a google managed environment (per the docs)

Can someone describe the correct process for setting up and running the admin SDK in local environments so that I can access service worker credentials using the JSONs locally, but I do not actually have to deploy the JSONS for production environments on google hardware?

Here is my code in `index.ts` where the SDK is being initialized.

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
initializeApp();

exports.StripeOnboarding = require("./Stripe/StripeOnboarding");
exports.StripeAccountUtils = require("./Stripe/StripeAccountUtils");

exports.EmailUserUtils = require("./SendgridAPI/EmailUserUtils");

exports.TokenSystem = require("./Utils/Authentication/TokenSystem")
```

Here is the WIP code where I require the credentials to generate a JWT using the `private_key` note the log messages return *undefined* in the code's current state, this is the issue.

```
export function  createCustomToken (uid: string) {

    const admin = require('firebase-admin');


    try {
        const adminCred = admin.credential;
        console.log(adminCred, adminCred.private_key, 'THIS IS ADMIN CRED')
        console.log('THIS IS PRIVATE KEY', adminCred.private_key)
        const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
        return jwt.sign({uid: uid}, adminCred.private_key, {
            algorithm: 'RS256',
            expiresIn: '1h',
            issuer: adminCred.client_email,
            audience: '', subject: adminCred.client_email
        });
    } catch (errorResult) {
        error(errorResult);
        throw new Error("could not create token");
    }

}
```

When starting the emulators using:
`$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="{ABSOLUTE SYSTEM PATH TO SERVICE WORKER JSON}"`

`firebase emulators:start --import ..\emulatorData\`

`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS={ABSOLUTE SYSTEM PATH TO SERVICE WORKER JSON}` also does not work.

I am on Windows.